# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS OEM

Tags: 14.04

Does Ubuntu offer an Original Equipment Manufacturer installation optiofor 14.04.1 LTS?  I intend to sell used PCs with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS preinstalled and I want my customers to be able to set up their own user name, password, etc.

Comment: I know when I use Unetbootin to create Xubuntu USB live sticks, one of the options on the menu is OEM INSTALL.  I have never tried it, but I am sure it gives the functionality you are asking for.  Try making one for Ubuntu and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ubuntu 14.04.1 does offer an OEM-Option.

See this wiki entry for a detailed Instruction:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview